# <span> padding with width 100% causing unexpected behaviour

Tags: html, css

How can I get my `span` element to fill up the width of its parent `div` element, while having some padding?


The code below causes its width to surpass that of its parent.


**Code**

```
    <div style="width: 30rem" id="parent">
      <span
        style="
          background-color: green;
          display: block;
          padding: 1rem;
          width: 100%;
        ">
       Span
     </span>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: i think it's because of padding. check [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of padding. your width is 100% plus padding. To prevent it use [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) property.

```css
#parent {
  border: 3px solid;
}

span {
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 30rem" id="parent">
  <span>
       Span
     </span>
</div>
```